# No Wireless interface on Ubuntu 14.04 with Broadcom driver on Asus R556L

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, asus

I can't seem to  enable the wireless interface on the newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Asus 14.04

I've tried the solutions on: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers?newreg=5703e76992bc4decba147e0d6a150aa2) 
but it still doesn't work
I've installed that `bcmwl-kernel-source` and `firmware-b43-installer`
 and `firmware-b43-installer` and reboot several times.
here's the result for the following command:
`rfkill list all`

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`
```

`lspci -vnn | grep Network`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

`iwconfig`
`eth0      no wireless extensions.`
`lo        no wireless extensions.`

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 08:62:66:e0:4f:bd
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=202.125.210.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:63 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7104000-f7104fff memory:f7100000-f7103fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7000000-f7007fff` <br><br>
```

Comment: I know you said you tried all the solutions, but can you try Oli's answer here? http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score -1):

My computer is an Asus A450JF. I have same problem as you. My solution:

```
sudo rmmod -f acer-wmi
```